# Pointer to struct with pointer to array of pointers to structs. Dynamic memory  in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory, pointers, dynamic

I am having trouble with some code in C accessing the contents of this chain of pointers:

I have these structs:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int hash;
    char string[10]; 
    void *memory;
} thing;

typedef struct {
    int num; 
    thing *thing;
} node;


typedef struct {
    int size;
    thing* things;
    node* nodes;
} t_system;
```

Ok. Now I initialize everything like this:

```
thing* things = NULL;
things = calloc(10, sizeof(thing));

node* nodes = NULL;
nodes = calloc(10, sizeof(node));

t_system* theSystem = NULL;
theSystem = calloc(1, sizeof(t_system));

    theSystem->things = things;
    theSystem->nodes = nodes;
```

And now, I want to set this:

```
theSystem->nodes[2].thing = &theSystem->things[1];
```

After that line, if I debug and set a breakpoint theSystem nodes points to 0x0

Where am I going wrong?

---

```
if (theSystem->nodes[2].thing == NULL) {
    theSystem->nodes[2].thing = &theSystem->things[1]; //this is executed
}
if (theSystem->nodes[2].thing == NULL) {
    //this is not executed...
}
```

---

I can do this:

```
theSystem->nodes[2].thing->hash = 123;
```

And debugging shows the correct value for hash, and thing, but not for nodes. it points to 0x0.

Comment: You are making something up here. The line `theSystem->nodes[2].thing = theSystem->things[1]` will not even compile. Left-hand side is a pointer. Right-hand side is a struct. Please, don't make up code. Post the real code or at least something sufficiently close to real code.

Comment: That is exactly why im here. `if (theSystem->nodes[2].thing == NULL)` is false, but debugging says otherwise.

Comment: No, no, no. Again, the code you posted *will not compile*. It cannot be run or debugged. The line I referred to is not compilable by any existing compiler, unless you are using something totally unknown. What compiler are you using?

Comment: As far as i know, im using gcc.

Comment: Well, I don't know what kind of major malfunction in GCC allows one to compile `theSystem->nodes[2].thing = theSystem->things[1]` line, but in any case that assignment makes no sense whatsoever. You cannot assign a `struct` to a pointer. The code is simply meaningless. What do you expect this assignment should do?

Comment: You are totally right, i was missing the &. Now it compiles.

Comment: Same thing, i still get 0x0 as pointer value.

Comment: At what moment exactly? In your original question you said it happened *after* that assignment. Later you seem to claim that the problem happens *before* the assignment. The way your code looks now, it seems to be working perfectly. Initial value of `theSystem->nodes[2].thing` is null. So you execute the assignment. The you do another check and it is no longer null. As it should be. So, what's the problem?

Comment: It always happen after the assignment. i can do what i have just added to the question, but it still makes no sense, i get `theSystem->nodes` 0x0.

Comment: I don't understand. You made an addition to your question, which says explicitly that the second `if` is *not executed*. That means that the pointer is *not zero*. Yet you keep claiming that it is *zero*. That's self-contradictory. So, what is it?

Comment: Have you seen the code i added?

Comment: What code specifically? You added code with two `if`s. That's the code I'm talking about. Your code says that the first `if` is *executed* and the second `if` is *not executed*. That's exactly how it should be. No problems here. You also added extra code with `theSystem->nodes[2].thing.hash = 123`, which is again non-compilable: `thing` is a *pointer* (please, stop posting fake code). So, where is the problem?

Comment: Well there is no problem at all. the debugger was some how frozen at old values. Thank you for your time, it now say it points to a real memory address.// If youd like add an answer so i can give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize nodes to NULL on this line:

```
node* nodes = NULL;
```

Then you assign nodes to theSystem->nodes on this line:

```
theSystem->nodes = nodes;
```

Since you never change the value of nodes in between, theSystem->nodes will also be NULL.

Are you sure the following line is correct:

```
tree = calloc(10, sizeof(node));
```

Shouldn't you assign this to nodes instead?

Comment: Yes that was wrong, but just in this question. The actual code is correct, i have updated the main question.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote

```
node* nodes = NULL;
tree = calloc(10, sizeof(node));
```

You should have written

```
node* nodes = NULL;
nodes = calloc(10, sizeof(node));
```

Comment: I have update the code to reflect this fix, please take a look.